# Mapping wordnet to other Ontologies

Tags: wordnet

Are there mappings available for wordnet 3.0 synsets to other ontologies like [Cyc](http://www.cyc.com/platform/researchcyc) , [YAGO](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/yago-naga/yago/) and [EuroWordNet](http://www.illc.uva.nl/EuroWordNet/) like [SUMO](http://www.ontologyportal.org/) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yago is [linked to Wordnet](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/yago-naga/yago/), and also to [SUMO](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~gdemelo/yagosumo/). Please check the links.

Comment: I have already browsed through these pages but couldn't get hold of these mappings. Can you point me where to look precisely. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: This page provides the links for Yago: http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/yago-naga/yago/downloads.html , you can see from the previews that yago types are linked to wordnet, in yagoTaxonomy for example. The yagoWordnetIds file can be used but the ids can also be obtained from parsing the YAGO class names